# How to copying FTP files to an specific folders.?

Tags: php, ftp, backup

I have **.txt** file named `files.txt` which contains a list of file names.

**files.txt**

```
index.php.bk-2013-12-02
index.php.bk-2013-12-07
index.php.bk-2013-12-10
index.php.bk-2013-12-20
index.php.bk-2013-12-26
function.php.bk-2013-12-20
function.php.bk-2013-12-23
contact.php.bk-2013-12-23
contact.php.bk-2013-12-30
```

I want to copy these files to the directory **backup**
NO need to recursive.. just wanna copy as it is.

My **httpdocs** folder looks like this

- **files.txt**
- index.php.bk-2013-12-02
- index.php.bk-2013-12-07
- index.php.bk-2013-12-10
- index.php.bk-2013-12-20
- index.php.bk-2013-12-26
- function.php.bk-2013-12-20
- function.php.bk-2013-12-23
- contact.php.bk-2013-12-23
- contact.php.bk-2013-12-30
- **backup**

after I execute the script file, the above mentioned **.php.bk** files must be copied in to the folder **backup**

How can I do that pals?
any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line and then just copy the file to your 'backup' folder:

```
$files = "files.txt";
$lines = file($files);
foreach($lines as $file)
{
    $file = trim($file);
    copy($dir . '/' . $file, $dir . '/backup/' . $file);
}
```

But that has nothing to do with FTP, right?

Also, if your files alway habe `.bak-` in their name, this may be easier:

```
foreach (glob("*.bk-*") as $filename) {
    copy($filename, 'backup/' . $filename);
}
```

Comment: yeah.. thanks.. but its copying the last file only from the **files.txt** list. also its changing the permission and owner group.. how can we overcome this.?

Comment: Of course it copies the files from the files.txt, but thats what you wantet, right? What does change permission, the copied files?

Comment: yeah thats right.. it's copying the file from the **files.txt** but its copying only one file which is in last at the list. eg: if I have 5 file names on **files.txt**then It's coping 5th file only. yup.. its changing the permission of copied files. not same with the original.

Comment: I habe updated my answer. I tested the code, it should work. The permissions of the files should be the persmission of the user who runs the php-script. So maybe you should change the user then...

Comment: it's working like a charm after I changed the code `copy($dir . '/' . $file, $dir . '/backup/' . $file);` to `copy($dir . '' . $file, $dir . 'backup/' . $file);` . thanks a lot..